# adding values from one column of a data frame into a new column of another dataframe if the first two columns in both match

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I have a data frame (d1) with 35K points and 2 columns. I have a second data frame (d2) with 352 points with 3 columns. What I have been trying to do is if d1$c1 and d1$c2 are equal to d2$c1 and d2$c2, then I would like to add the value of d2$c3 into a new column in d1 (say d1$c3).
The dataframe d1 is similar to one below.
D2is basically a smaller version of D1,and D1 has the same values repeated multiple times

```
**D1**
|C1 | C2  |      
|---|:---:|
|1  |1    |
|1  |1    |
|1  |2    |
|2  |1    |
|2  |2    |
|2  |2    |
|2  |2    |
|3  |1    |
|3  |2    |
|3  |3    |
|3  |1    |
|3  |1    |

**D2**

|C1 | C2  | C3  |
|---|:---:|----:|
|1  |1    |a    |
|1  |2    |b    |
|1  |3    |c    | 
|2  |2    |b    |
|3  |1    |c    |   
|3  |2    |a    |
|3  |3    |b    |
```

now what I would like to do is this

```
if((d1$c1 == d2$c1) & (d1$c2 == d2$c2))
{
d1$c3 = d2$c3
}
```

post running the loop the resulting D1 should look something like with matching entries from D2, being added in a new col in D1

```
 **D1**
    |C1 | C2  | new C3|      
    |---|:---:|--------
    |1  |1    |a
    |1  |1    |a
    |1  |2    |b
    |2  |1    |a
    |2  |2    |b
    |2  |2    |b
    |2  |2    |b
    |3  |1    |c
    |3  |2    |a
    |3  |3    |b
    |3  |1    |c
    |3  |1    |c
```

But I end up getting error that there is a length mismatch.

The code I have tried is

```
for(i in 1:length(D1$c1))
{
if(((D1$C1 = D2$c1) & (D1$C2 = D2$c2))
{
  D1$c3[i] = D2$c3
}
}
```

I also tried to create a new data frame with one column to add the values from D2

```
x = data.frame(length(D1))

for(i in (D1$C1 & D1$C2))
{
  for(j in D2$C1 & D2$C2)
  {
    if(i == j)
    { 
      x = (D2$C3)
              }
  }
}
```

Both of these have not worked.

Comment: it looks like you want to use the `merge` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by=c("C1","C2"))
```

Output is:

```
   C1 C2   C3
1   1  1    a
2   1  1    a
3   1  2    b
4   2  1 <NA>
5   2  2    b
6   2  2    b
7   2  2    b
8   3  1    c
9   3  2    a
10  3  3    b
11  3  1    c
12  3  1    c
```

Sample data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(C1 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), C2 = c(1, 
1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1)), .Names = c("C1", "C2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))

df2 <- structure(list(C1 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3), C2 = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 
1, 2, 3), C3 = c("a", "b", "c", "b", "c", "a", "b")), .Names = c("C1", 
"C2", "C3"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake not expressing the data frames the correct way. The longer data frame with 35k points has column names different from the shorter df, d2 with 352 points. would this work if I just renamed the columns with same names?

Comment: sorry I just had a doubt which I mentioned in the above comment. Once that has been answered, I will mark it so it can be considered closed.

Comment: Renaming columns could be one of the option. If you don't want to rename then maybe this small change in above code helps - `left_join(df2, by=c("df1_C1_columnname"="df2_C1_columnname", "df1_C2_columnname" = "df2_C2_columnname"))`

Answer (score 0):

with base R, it is the merge function:

```
set.seed(654321)
d1 <- data.frame(C1=rep(1:3, each=6), C2=sample(3, 6*3, replace=TRUE))
d2 <- data.frame(C1=rep(1:3, 3), C2=rep(1:3, each=3), C3=sample(letters[1:3], 9, replace=TRUE))
merge(d1, d2, by=c("C1", "C2"))
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake not expressing the data frames the correct way. The longer data frame with 35k points has column names different from the shorter df, d2 with 352 points. would this work if I just renamed the columns with same names?

Comment: Then you can use by.x=c(<d1 column names>) and by.y=c(<d2 column names>) to specify different columns